# How do I get the search to work like this again?

Tags: 20.04, directory, settings, search

I have a bit of a mystery and I'm not sure what to do about it. I have a lot of text documents with emails (etc) in them in my 'Documents' folder in the Home directory. I have used the Ubuntu (regular) search on my files before and decided that it was totally rubbish and so installed 'Catfish' which has been helping me a lot.

However, just a moment ago I went into the Documents folder and did a search for my sisters name ,using the regular search, expecting the usual rubbish results. Regular search suddenly gave me all the files that ***contained*** her name (which was a lot more than usual). I tried again with my dogs name to see if it did the same and it did. It was wonderful.
So I put a shortcut to Documents on the desktop and changed it's icon so I could use the 'new search' when-ever I felt like it. For some reason though this stopped the 'new search' from working and I can't get it back.

I am not mistaking it for the 'Catfish' program as the layout is different looking. How do I get it back? Was it just a fluke or is there something I deleted or unticked that turned it off again?

Comment: How did you create the shortcut to Documents? Does the search still work as you described from the Documents folder?

Comment: I just went into the Home directory and right clicked the Documents folder; clicked 'create link' on the little menu and then cut and pasted the shortcut to the desktop....but I have tried searching just now from the folder itself and it worked in the 'new' way! It doesn't work from the shortcut. Thank you, you solved the mystery!!

Comment: I forget how to mark your answer as the right one...How do I do that and mark this as solved?